# Create an json object in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create a json string like in the example below and I am thinking of using a dict that I can ultimately json.dumps to a json string. I will build this dict in a loop. This is what the json should look like

```
{
"big-data-list" :[
    {
        "indexnum": "1",
        "components" : 
            [
                {
                    "key": "some-key1",
                    "item" :"item name",
                    "data" :"some string",
                }
            ]
    },
    {
        "indexnum": "2",
        "components" : 
            [
               {
                    "key": "some-key2",
                    "item" :"item name 2",
                    "data" :"some string 2",
               },
               {
                    "key": "some-key3",
                    "item" :"item name 3",
                    "data" :"some string 3",
               }

            ]
    }
}
```

Here is what I tried without a loop to see how things work

```
bigdata= {}
indexnum= {}
componentList = {}
indexnum["components"] = {}
 
indexnum["mileage"] = 20
componentList["key"] = "some-key1"
componentList["item"] = "item name" 
componentList["data"] = "some string" 
indexnum["components"][0] = componentList
componentList["key"] = "some-key2"
componentList["item"] = "item name 2" 
componentList["data"] = "some string 2" 
indexnum["components"][1] = componentList
print(json.dumps(indexnum))
```

What I end up getting looks like this:

```
{"components": {"0": {"key": "somekey2", "item": "fuel2"}, "1": {"key": "somekey2", "item": "fuel2"}}, "mileage": 20}
```

How do I build the dict so I can json dump it in the way I need to? Is there a better way to come up with such a json object as represented in the example above?

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. JSON is generally also valid Python (with the exception of some constants like ``true``/``True``) so you can literally just write down what you want. Note that your code has only *one* object ``componentList``, which is repeatedly referenced and modified – each reference will see the same final state upon dumping it.

Comment: if you're using a dict with a key for index and a key for components, are you sure you don't want a list of dicts, or a list of lists of dicts?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I didn't get what you meant by JSON is valid Python. did you mean python objects can be dumped as  json? I want to loop thru a source json object which is much large and more nested and create a flatter json with lesser number of fields. I thought of converting the source json to a dict first and then using json dumps on that dict. I was getting an error on the add, update and append methods I used on the json object `indexnum`. Im paraphrasing here but the error basically said there is no such method for add or update or extend on the object.

Comment: I mean that if you want "this JSON", you can generally just write it – (almost) the same syntax describes the equivalent Python data structure. For example, instead of (incorrectly!) working with ``componentList``, you can just do ``indexnum["components"][0] = {"key": "some-key1", "item": "item name", "data": "some string" }``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically just need to work on your logic to put your data in the appropriate structure of `dict`s and `list`s.
Below is an example of a loop that puts some data into the specified structure:

```py
>>> # say you originally have your data in the following list
... lists_of_components = [
...     [("some-key1", "item name", "some string")],
...     [("some-key2", "item name 2", "some string 2"),
...      ("some-key3", "item name 3", "some string 3")],
... ]
... bigdata = {}
... bigdata["big-data-list"] = []
... for i, components in enumerate(lists_of_components, 1):
...     bigdata["big-data-list"].append({
...         "indexnum": str(i),
...         "components": [
...             {k: v for k, v in zip(["key", "item", "data"], component)}
...             for component in components]
...     })
... print(json.dumps(bigdata, indent=4))
{
    "big-data-list": [
        {
            "indexnum": "1",
            "components": [
                {
                    "key": "some-key1",
                    "item": "item name",
                    "data": "some string"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "indexnum": "2",
            "components": [
                {
                    "key": "some-key2",
                    "item": "item name 2",
                    "data": "some string 2"
                },
                {
                    "key": "some-key3",
                    "item": "item name 3",
                    "data": "some string 3"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```